# Numpy Compare unequal rows and make both array of same dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
a=   
[[43655,    1428,     0, 2554]      
[44580,  1428,     0,  2555]  
[44930,  1428,     0,  2556]  
[47708,  1428,     0,  2557]]     
b=   
[[41641,  1428,     0, 2554]  
[44075,  1428,     0,  2555]  
[44901,  1428,     1,  2556]  
[45377,  1428,     0,  2557]  
[48056,  1428,     0,  2558]]


New  b= 
[[41641,  1428,     0, 2554]  
[44075,  1428,     0,  2555]  
[44901,  1428,     1,  2556]  
[45377,  1428,     0,  2557]
```

I have two numpy array with unequal rows. For eg. Array `a` has 4 rows while array `b` has 5 rows.
Edit: No. of rows in array 'b' is greater than array 'a'. Every element of a[:,3] lies in  b[:,3]. Is there any function that extract only the rows of array b whose b[:,3]=a[:,3]

Comment: Seems that the output is not what you have want? and how you want to compare the columns and reduce the `b` based on what logic?

Comment: Every element in a[:,3] is a subset of b[:,3]. So I was thinking to compare a[:,3] with b[:,3] and extract index of b[:,3] where it matches with a[:,3]. In above eg. index would be i=[0,1,2,3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare your the elements of 3rd column using `zip` and `np.equal` within a list comprehension then convert the result to a numpy array and get the desire rows from array `b`.

```
>>> b[np.array([np.equal(*I) for I in zip(a[:,3],b[:,3])])]
array([[41641,  1428,     0,  2554],
       [44075,  1428,     0,  2555],
       [44901,  1428,     1,  2556],
       [45377,  1428,     0,  2557]])
```

If the order is not important for you you can use `np.in1d` :

```
>>> b[np.in1d(b[:,3],a[:,3])]
array([[41641,  1428,     0,  2554],
       [44075,  1428,     0,  2555],
       [44901,  1428,     1,  2556],
       [45377,  1428,     0,  2557]])

>>> a=np.array([[100, 1], [101, 4], [106, 6], [104, 10]])
>>> b= np.array([[ 1, 1], [ 2, 2], [ 3, 3], [ 4, 4], [ 5, 5], [ 6, 6], [ 7, 7], [ 8, 8], [ 9, 9], [10, 10]])
>>> 
>>> b[np.in1d(b[:,1],a[:,1])]
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 4,  4],
       [ 6,  6],
       [10, 10]])
```

Comment: >>> a
array([[100,   1],  
       [101,   4], 
       [106,   6],
       [104,  10]])   >>> b
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 2,  2],
       [ 3,  3],
       [ 4,  4],
       [ 5,  5],
       [ 6,  6],
       [ 7,  7],
       [ 8,  8],
       [ 9,  9],
       [10, 10]]) is not showing the same behavior. New b should be=b
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 4,  4],
       [ 6,  6],
       [10, 10]])

Comment: @HaWa So the order is not important for you! let me update

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the last element of an array by doing `a[:-1]`

Therefore you can omit the last row of an array by doing;

```
a[:,3] 
b[:-1,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know how much longer `b` is than `a` then you can just use

```
b[:a.shape[0]]
```

This will grab enough rows of `b` to compare to `a`.

So to grab a particular column like in your example, it would be

```
b[:a.shape[0], 3]
```

This technique will even work in the other direction (if `b` is smaller than `a`).